# How to redirect the output of a command into a txt file?

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to place  the output of the following command into a file called log.txt the command is the following

readlink -f var > log.txt

I basically just need to be able to put the file location into that file but it has to be done through code not through the terminal

```
delete () {  #deletes all files in the arguments and places it in the recycle bin

shift
for var in "$@"
do
mv $var ~/RecycleBin
echo $var > log.txt
readlink -f var > log.txt
done

 }
```

for some reason its not writing anything into the file file remains blank.

I changed it to this

```
for var in "$@"  
do  
mv $var ~/RecycleBin  
echo $var >> log.txt  
readlink -f $var >> log.txt  
done  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$var` to access content of  a variable, not `var`.

Use `>>` to append content to a file. `>` overwrites an existing file.

Quote variables with double quotes: `"$var"`

Comment: I changed it to the following

    for var in "$@"  
do  
    mv $var ~/RecycleBin  
    echo $var >> log.txt  
    readlink -f $var >> log.txt  
done  

}  

but its still not writing into the file, the file log.txt isn't updated at all.

Comment: How do you use function `delete` in your script? Are there any error messages?

Comment: no there is no error the function works it places the file the user chooses in the recyclebin folder just need to write its original location into a file called log.txt

Comment: This may help you to troubleshoot the problem: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I got it to work! it writes to the file, but its writing the readlink -f $var as text into the file not the actual command output just the command sentence